# Calculate average of displayed values in a Power BI report

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I am having real trouble trying to calculate an average of values in a table.

[Table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WO0E.png)

The table seems simple enough. It shows the number of sick days, in each period and the corresponding number of employees employed at the end of each period (See below). This is so I can create an average number of sick days for each period.

```
Employees At End Of Period = 
VAR selectedDate = MAX(dim_Dates[Calendar_Date])

RETURN 

SUMX('dim_Employee_Basic Info',
VAR employeeStartDate = [Start Date]
VAR employeeEndDate = [Left Date]
RETURN IF(employeeStartDate<= selectedDate && OR(employeeEndDate >= selectedDate, employeeEndDate=BLANK() ),1,0)
)
```

My issue is that I do not want to use the number of employees at the end of each period, but the average of the number of employees at the end of each period over the year. ie. Sum all 12 values and divide by 12. The average in the example should be 713.83.

How on earth do I calculate an average of a measure? I have read the internet and been unable to find anything that gets me even close to an answer!

Tried everything I could think of. Any help would be appreciated